# Remotely connect to spark on yarn cluster in client mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rstudio, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

I have a remote spark on yarn cluster that if I use rstudio server(web version) hosted on that cluster to connect in client mode I can do the following:

```
sc <- SparkR::sparkR.init(master = "yarn-client")
```

However if I try to use rstudio on my local machine to connect to that spark cluster the same way then I have errors:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master
...
ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread nioEventLoopGroup-2-2
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
ERROR RBackendHandler: createSparkContext on org.apache.spark.api.r.RRDD failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
```

A more detailed error message on hadoop application tracking page is like this:

```
User:   blueivy
Name:   SparkR
Application Type:   SPARK
Application Tags:   
State:  FAILED
FinalStatus:    FAILED
Started:    27-Oct-2015 11:07:09
Elapsed:    4mins, 39sec
Tracking URL:   History
Diagnostics:    
Application application_1445628650748_0027 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1445628650748_0027_000002 exited with exitCode: 10
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master:8088/proxy/application_1445628650748_0027/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1445628650748_0027_02_000001
Exit code: 10
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=10:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:267)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1143)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:618)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 10
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

I have the same configurations and environment for hadoop and spark with remote cluster: spark 1.5.1, hadoop 2.6.0 and ubuntu 14.04. Anyone can help me find what's my mistake here?

Comment: I think, you don't have correct yarn configuration on your local machine. Also it worth to check whether your yarn task manager accepts requests from your local address. (Usually clusters configured to work only in some subnetwork for security and performance reasons).

Comment: Do you (@DmitriySelivanov) how do you check the yarn configuration for this?

Comment: This seems to me like a permission issue...do you have `kerberos` or something enabled?